# Redirect www to subdomain with masking

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm totally stuck here, and I've read and tried countless suggestions, but it still doesn't work. I would really appreciate a custom solution to this.

I have a wordpress site installed at subdomain wordpress.domain.com what is actually a subdirectory located in \wordpress.

While my redirect is working, and users are forwarded from www to wordpress subdomain, I need the users **not** to see the wordpress.domain.com - i.e. I need them to see only  www.domain.com all the time.

This is what I have in my .htaccess file, but it does nothing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wordpress/(.*)$  http://wordpress.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

For the reference here's the full htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

#Options +FollowSymLinks
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wordpress.domain.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]


# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+)
wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Do you have access to the full config for domain.com or just the .htaccess? Sounds like you need a reverse proxy to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. Since this was getting too complicated, I've decided to move wordpress under root and all is well. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wordpress.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I was getting browser ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.